# DelphiXE3 and invalid generic typecast

Tags: delphi, generics, casting, delphi-xe3

Delphi2010 compiles my TObjectListEnumerator class without error, 
but DelphiXE3 gives compiler error:   E2089: Invalid typecast

What is wrong with this?

```
    TObjectListEnumerator<T> = class
      private
        fList     : TObjectList;
        fIndex    : integer;
        fMaxIndex : integer;
        function GetCurrent : T;
      public
        constructor Create(List: TObjectList);
        function MoveNext : Boolean;
        property Current  : T read GetCurrent;
      end;

    constructor TObjectListEnumerator<T>.Create(List: TObjectList);
    begin
      inherited Create;
      fList     := List;
      fIndex    := -1;
      fMaxIndex := fList.Count-1;
    end;

    function TObjectListEnumerator<T>.MoveNext: Boolean;
    begin
      Inc(fIndex);
      Result := not(fIndex > fMaxIndex);
    end;

    function TObjectListEnumerator<T>.GetCurrent: T;
    begin
      Result := T(fList[fIndex]);  // <-- E2089: Invalid typecast 
    end;
```

Comment: Not really an answer to your question, but since you are using generics, why don't you switch from the non-parameterized `TObjectList` to `TObjectList<T>` from `System.Generics.Collections`? I guess that it would automatically help you so you wouldn't need the typecast there.

Comment: Thanks Pateman, nice hint! If I use TObjectList<T>, I don't need TObjectListEnumerator<T> at all.

Answer (score 2):

[As the documentation states](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE3/de/System.Contnrs.TObjectList.Items): the property `Items` of `Contnrs.TObjectList` has the type `TObject`:

```
property Items[Index: Integer]: TObject read GetItem write SetItem; default;
```

On the other hand, the type parameter `T` is unconstrained and can be any type, for example a value type like `Integer`.

If you add a [generic type constraint](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE3/en/Constraints_in_Generics#Class_Type_Constraints), the code should compile:

```
TObjectListEnumerator<T: TObject> = class
```

Comment: If first thought about `TObjectListEnumerator<T: class> = class` but documentation is [saying](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE3/en/Constraints_in_Generics#Class_Constraint): "This means that the actual type must be a reference type, that is, a class or _interface_ type".